# Associative array to table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an JSON (abbreviated version) as described below.

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {"name": "Start", "value": "Ready"}, 
        {"name": "Date", "value": "2017-09-11"}, 
        {"name": "Crew", "value": "Crew 3"}]
}
```

I am trying to read the values from JSON to generate a table in [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/).
Each ***name*** element is setup as a column header and I am trying to read each ***value*** value from the JSON to the correct column.

My display should look like below.

**|  Start   |   Date     |   Crew   |**
|  Ready   | 2017-09-11 |  Crew 3  |

I create the schema in Taleau as below.

```
myConnector.getSchema = function (schemaCallback) {
    var cols = [
        { id : "start", alias : "Start", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string },
        { id : "date", alias : "Date", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.datetime },
        { id : "crew", alias : "Crew", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string }];
```

And my JavaScript to generate this is:

```
var resp = response; // Response data from some API call - JSON as described above
var tableData = []; 
// Iterate over the JSON object
for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
    tableData.push(
        { "start": resp[1]['value'] },
        { "date": resp[2]['value'] },
        { "crew": resp[3]['value'] });
        }

        table.appendRows(tableData);
        doneCallback();
    });
}
```

However, when this is generated in Tableau, each value value is in the correct column, but each value value is in a new row. Rather than all values in 1 row.

E.g.

**|  Start   |   Date     |   Crew   |**

|  Ready   |     -    |     -     |

|  -   | 2017-09-11 |  -  |

|  -   |   -   |  Crew 3  |

How do I loop through the JSON and add each value to the tableData object so all values are in the same row?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but from your output it seems you might need to add the data with and object with all the keys set to match columns: `{start: 'check', date: 'this', crew:'row'}`,can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Why are you pushing the values separately and not as a single object?

Comment: Can you change `tableData.push(
        { "start": resp[1]['value'] },
        { "date": resp[2]['value'] },
        { "crew": resp[3]['value'] });
        }` to `tableData.push({ "start": resp[1]['value'] ,
         "date": resp[2]['value'],
         "crew": resp[3]['value']});
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put everything into an array of objects. From here you can iterate over the values and insert them into your table.

```js
const data = {"artists": [{"name": "Start", "value": "Ready"},{"name": "Date", "value": "2017-09-11"},{ "name": "Crew", "value": "artists Crew 1" }],"labor":[{"name": "Start", "value":"Ready"},{"name": "Date", "value": "2017-09-2"},{ "name": "Crew", "value": " labor Crew 2" }],accountant: [{"name": "Start", "value": "Ready"},{"name": "Date", "value": "2017-09-13"},{ "name": "Crew", "value": "account Crew 3" }],"somethingElse":[{"name": "Start", "value": "Ready"},{"name": "Date", "value": "2017-09-14"},{ "name": "Crew", "value": "somethingElse Crew 4"}],},
tableData =Object.entries(data).map(x => ({ Ready: x[1][0].value, Date: x[1][1].value, Crew: x[1][2].value }));
console.log(tableData);
```